# Plot of vector function which can't be evaluated with different colors

Tags: plotting

I have a function which returns a vector, like this:

```
f[x_] := With[{u = MixedFractionParts[x]}, UnitVector[4, u[[1]]] u[[2]]]
```

and would like to plot it:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 4}]
```

This gives me a plot where all lines are plotted in the default blue color, however I would like each of them to be plotted in a different color. Normally I would use evaluate, e.g. `Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 4}, Evaluated->True]`, but that doesn't work and gives errors like "Part 2 of MixedFractionParts[x] does not exist".

How can I plot this function with a different color per dimension?

Answer (score 4):

### Edit

Since `Plot` have the attribute `HoldAll`,

```
Attributes[Plot]
(* {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

`Plot` can't see the structure of `f[x]` until give the values of `x` so `Evaluate` can not work.( `Evaluate[f[x]]` get error).

By now,we have to tell `Plot` the structure of `f[x]`, that is what the original way which use `Part`.

Here we gave another approach.

```
Clear[n, f, plot, colors];
n = 10;
f[x_] := 
  With[{u = MixedFractionParts[x]}, UnitVector[n, u[[1]]] u[[2]]];
plot = Plot[f[x], {x, 1, n + 1}];
colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Subdivide[0, 1, n];
Block[{e = 0}, plot /. Line[pts_] :> {colors[[++e]], Line[pts]}]
```

[image]

### Original

```
Plot[{f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]], f[x][[3]], f[x][[4]]}, {x, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for an approach which works for various n..

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := 
 With[{u = MixedFractionParts[x]}, UnitVector[4, u[[1]]] u[[2]]]

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose@Table[f[x], {x, 1, 4, 0.01}],
 DataRange -> {1, 4},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For variable `n`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, n_Integer?Positive] := 
 With[{u = MixedFractionParts[x]}, UnitVector[n, u[[1]]] u[[2]]]

n = 6;

ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[f[#, n] & /@ Range[1, n, 0.01]],
 DataRange -> {1, n}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So Plot is not able to do this?